# convert spanish characters in HTML doc

Tags: html, utf-8, subsystem

I have a HTML file and it has some information in spanish. I am using a third party control to convert this HTML file into RTF document. The third party software I am using is Subsystems HTML Addon.

The HTML file has

```
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

I think the subsystems software is not able to recognize the characters greater than 127.

I tried replacing the characters with ASCII>127 to their HTML entity code For ex, ò with `&#149;` and then sending the document to converter but that didn't help.

Any one has any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try just asking their technical support? The [product page](http://www.subsystems.com/htw.htm) says it supports Arabic/Hebrew and Asian languages, so it sounds like they definitely support values above ASCII 127. It's probably an issue with getting the right encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The magic word is encoding. The question is what encoding your HTML file is in, and what encoding you need in your RTF file.

[Here is some very good basic reading on the issue](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) if you're interested. Otherwise, you'll have to determine the HTML files actual, and the RTF file's actual encodings.